# How to remove all files matching specific file content in HDFS?

Tags: hdfs, hadoop2

By mistake, using NiFi, huge number of files got generated in HDFS directory with content "val3val2val1". I want to remove all files matching this content using HDFS command. Please advise

Comment: You can write a custom script to remove all files.
Assuming all files are under same hdfs directory and all are generated in same timeframe.
Use a loop for path and grep the files contaning the pattern and save a list of files to be deleted.
while read file `hadoop fs -ls -r -t path` 
do
hadoop fs -cat file |grep pattern
if [ $? == 0 ];then
echo $file >> files_to_be_delted.txt
fi
done 

Something similar type of code should get your work done to get list of files to be deleted. Finally cross verify and delete those files.

Comment: thanks @yammanuruarun